# Prove that $f$ is an increasing function if $f'(x)$ is more than zero for all real values for $x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I'm having some difficulty with proving this theory. What I do know is how to prove that it is a constant function when $f'(x) = 0$ by simplying assuming that f is not constant and contradict the supposition. In this case, what should I do instead?

Comment: What is the definition of an increasing function? Suppose, for contradiction, that there exists an $f$ that does have a strictly positive derivative everywhere, but is not a strictly increasing function.

Comment: Use the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f'(x) > 0$ everywhere means $f$ is continuous everywhere.

And the mean value theorem says that for any $a, b; a < b$ that there is a $c: a < c < b$ where $f'(c)=\frac {f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$.

But we know $f'(c) > 0$ so $f(b) > f(a)$.

Comment: The denominator should be $b-a$ but otherwise this is correct.

Comment: Argh... it's late.... don't know what I was thinkin'....

Comment: It's fine, I fixed it for you :)

Comment: I've got to admit that its so intuitive to take positive derivative as increasing almost by definition.

Comment: Indeed, but a rigorous proof does not hurt. So long as one does not take the mean value theorem for granted, and is sure to prove that as well, of course.